# mod_rewrite issue with parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^portfolio-single/([^/.]+)/?$ portfolio-single.php?id=$1 [L]

<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all 
order deny,allow
</Files>

Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 405 /error.php
ErrorDocument 408 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
ErrorDocument 502 /error.php
ErrorDocument 504 /error.php
```

Currently all pages that end with the php extension are working fine. So for example `www.somewebsite.com/blog.php` is now accessable via `/blog`. However I want a certain page, namely, `portfolio-single.php?id=123` to be accessible via `/portfolio-single/123`. The 4th line you can see code that I took from this [website](http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/), and I have been trying to get it to work but keep getting a 404 when I access portfolio-single via `/portfolio-single/123`. What am I missing? A follow up question is if I have to reboot XAMPP for changes to the .htaccess file to take effect (so far it has worked without).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding `.php` extension you must check whether corresponding `.php` file exists firts:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^portfolio-single/([^/.]+)/?$ portfolio-single.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try swapping the two rules. The last rule is more specific so it should match first.

---

While your current approach works, it's more common to use one catch-all rule and a generic handle script which does the routing.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ handler.php?path=$1 [L]
```

Then `handler.php` can decide what to do with `blog` and `portfolio-single/x` and `non-existing-page`.

The router can now be implemented in PHP which gives you more freedom, like dynamically adding routes and matches based on more than a regexp.

Another advantage of this approach is that your application now has a single point of entry. This makes bootstrapping much easier since there is only one path.

Comment: thank you for the additional information. although since i only need to do this on one page i think i'll leave it for now. but i am definitely going to explore routers more!